# mod_wsgi and multiple installations of python

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi

This is kind of a continuation of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6449400/no-module-named-os-found-django-mod-wsgi-apache-2-2) question, but it has deviated so I started a new one. I'd like to use Python 2.5 instead of OS X's default 2.6. I've set this up for my terminal and whatnot, but whenever apache runs it gives me the following error output:

```
[Thu Jun 23 00:01:42 2011] [warn] Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Thu Jun 23 00:01:42 2011] [warn] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.5.4.
[Thu Jun 23 00:01:42 2011] [warn] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.6.1.
[Thu Jun 23 00:01:42 2011] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Thu Jun 23 00:01:42 2011] [notice] Digest: done
[Thu Jun 23 00:01:42 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.17 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.17 OpenSSL/0.9.8l DAV/2 mod_wsgi/3.3 Python/2.6.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

I've set WSGIPythonPath to match what sys.path gives me in the python shell:

```
WSGIPythonPath /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5
```

Still no luck. Ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Building mod_wsgi using python 2.5 on Snow Leopard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3534508/building-mod-wsgi-using-python-2-5-on-snow-leopard)

Comment: Interesting thread, thats my problem too. so how can host multiple sites which uses multiple python versions on single box?

Answer (score 11):

You should use the following directives depending on which version of mod_wsgi you use

For mod_wsgi 1.x:

```
WSGIPythonExecutable /path/to/python/2.5/exe
```

For mod_wsgi 2.x:

```
WSGIPythonHome /path/to/python/2.5/exe/directory
```

The `WSGIPythonPath` is just intended to add your own libraries to the Python Path in the WSGI context.

Link to documentation: http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIPythonExecutable

Comment: I've looked at `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/bin` where python2.5 executable lives, and added `WSGIPythonHome /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/bin` to my httpd.conf, but still the same result

Comment: Try `WSGIPythonHome /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/`

Comment: Do you use mod_wsgi and mod_python at the same time on your server ?

Answer (score 4):

```
[Thu Jun 23 00:01:42 2011] [warn] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.5.4.
[Thu Jun 23 00:01:42 2011] [warn] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.6.1.
```

These two lines tell you that mod_wsgi was compiled for the wrong Python version, so you need to recompile it with the correct `--with-python` directive. See http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickInstallationGuide#Configuring_The_Source_Code.

Comment: I compiled it specifically for Python 2.5.4 -- what I don't understand is why it is continuing to run it in 2.6.1

Comment: ah, sry I misunderstood your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I resolved the similar problem on CentOS 6.7, since the default was Python 2.6, I needed to install Python 2.7 to support a Django website.

First I installed Python 2.7 with `yum`:

```
yum install python27 python27-python-devel python27-MySQL-python
```

the installation path of Python 2.7 is `/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/bin/python`

Then we need to re-compile mod_wsgi with the new paths, and here are the commands:

```
wget https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/archive/4.4.21.tar.gz
tar -xzf 4.4.21.tar.gz
cd mod_wsgi-4.4.21
./configure --with-python=/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/bin/python LDFLAGS="-R/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64"
make  && make install
service httpd restart
tail /var/log/httpd/error_log
```

The key point here is that mod_wsgi needs to locate the `libpython2.7.so` under `/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64` in my Python 2.7 installation.

Another important note in my installation was that I had to install `python27-MySQL-python` with `yum`, otherwise I got an error when installing it with `pip` as below:

```
pip install MySQL-python
```

Comment: Exactly my situation. Thanks! Too bad we have to recompile mod_wsgi, then maintain it after that.