# Getting DatabaseError, no such table with sqlite3

Tags: django, sqlite

First time deploying a project. Getting DatabaseError when navigating to a view that modifies or creates Objects in the db. The error I get is:

> #### DatabaseError at /uap_app/coach/request/
>
> no such table: uap_app_coachrequest

with Traceback found [here](http://dpaste.com/872505/):

Suggestions include ensuring that `settings.py` reflects the full path for the db, which I have already done.  Additionally, I have checked and ensured that all of the tables have been properly created by querying within the sqlite env.  Tables initially created via `manage.py sql uap_app` and `syncdb`

in `settings.py`:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
    'NAME': '/var/www/cscc/uap_prod_db2.sqlite3',
```

Please let me know if there is anything else I should add?

Setup: Django1.4, Python2.7, Apache2.2, mod_wsgi, sqlite3, CentOS

Comment: Can you post your models as they were when you ran `syncdb`? Do you happen to still have the trace of the work that was done when you ran `syncdb` - it would tell you what tables were created.

Comment: yep! resulting from [sql uap_app](http://dpaste.com/hold/872513/) and from [syncdb](http://dpaste.com/hold/872514/)

Comment: Has your database user been granted the correct permissions to see and modify that table?

Comment: I added r/w permissions to all users but not sure if that is adequate or correct? used `chmod a+w+r` for the db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! My machine had multiple python versions installed so I needed to ensure that it pointed to the python2.7 executable instead of the default system-wide installed python.

added this line to `httpd.conf`:

> `WSGIPythonExecutable \usr\local\bin\python2.7`

got an error from apache saying `Invalid command 'WSGIPythonExecutable'`-- apparently used only for a previous version of mod_wsgi 1.x ([as per this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6450459/mod-wsgi-and-multiple-installations-of-python))

so then i tried adding this line to `httpd.conf`:

> `WSGIPythonExecutable \usr\local`

and voila! It worked!

Thanks to [unsorted](https://stackoverflow.com/users/146478/unsorted) for additional help

Comment: Accept you answer (by click) or write "SOLVED" to the title to be clear that other people need not to think about the question.

Comment: ah.. thanks! i cant yet accept the answer (have to wait til tomorrow) but will add solved