# How to execute Python from virtualenv for Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, centos7, wsgi, django-wsgi

I have installed Django 2.0.5 on CentOS 7 server with Python 3.7.0 following the instruction of [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-on-centos-7)
post.

After adding conf file, I have got following error

```
mod_wsgi (pid=21374): Target WSGI script '/home/user/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
mod_wsgi (pid=21374): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/user/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py", line 18, in <module>
    from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
  File "/home/user/myproject_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.utils.version import get_version
  File "/home/user/myproject_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/version.py", line 61, in <module>
    @functools.lru_cache()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'lru_cache'
```

Which indicates **wsgi.py** file executed by Python 2.7.5 which is my server's default Python version.

To confirm this I have added version and `$PYTHONPATH` to **error_log** from **wsgi.py**.

```
ERROR:root:Python Version: 2.7.5
ERROR:root:['/home/user/myproject', '/home/user/myproject_env/bin/python3.7', 
'/home/user/myproject_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages', '/usr/lib64/python27.zip', 
'/usr/lib64/python2.7', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-tk', 
'/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload', 
'/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
```

It confirms that it is executing Python 2.7.5 instead Python 3.7.0.

How can I change the Django Python Path to execute `Python 3` from `virtualenv`?

**EDIT:**

Here is my **django.conf** file:

```
Alias /static /home/user/myproject/static
<Directory /home/user/myproject/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /home/user/myproject/myproject>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess myproject python-path=/home/user/myproject:/home/user/myproject_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup myproject
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/user/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mod\_wsgi and multiple installations of python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6450459/mod-wsgi-and-multiple-installations-of-python)

Comment: In case of a virtual env, specify the path to its executable: in your case it should be `/home/user/myproject_env/bin/python3`.

Comment: that path is already in path list mentioned in post @hoefling

Comment: I'm not talking about `WSGIPythonPath`, but about `WSGIPythonExecutable`. Please read the answer to the linked question carefully.

Comment: I have used `WSGIDaemonProcess myproject python-path=/home/user/myproject:/home/user/myproject_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages`. adding `WSGIPythonExecutable` gives me following error during server restart `Job for httpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.` @hoefling

Comment: What version of `mod_wsgi` you are using?

Comment: WSGIPythonExecutable was apparently removed in mod_wsgi 2.x.

Comment: mod_wsgi version is 3.4

Comment: Again - please read the answer to the linked question. For `mod_wsgi>2`, the property was renamed to `WSGIPythonHome`.